# Share and use SMB with 4 routers

Tags: networking, router, internet, smb

I have a total of 4 routers at home, I will explain my network diagram
and I hope you can help me.

I have in one of the rooms the main router that connected to the internet provider With optical fibers, this router is generic and marketed by my internet company. This router has a Windows 11 computer connected to the LAN from which I am trying to share via SMB, also from that router I have another LAN output connected to the router (Xiaomi AX5400) that is in another room and from this Xiaomi AX5400 (which is connected to the main router) it outputs to another Two LAN cables that are connected to 2 more routers the same Xiaomi AX5400 devices that are in the other rooms (in total 3 Xiaomi router devices and 1 generic ISP router) so basically I have a router in
each room, I will try to make it simple for you:

My network setup:

Generic optical fiber of main router connected to ISP (to this router the computer With win11 is connected via LAN) -> LAN to Xiaomi AX5400 -> 2 more LAN cables from this router to 2 other Xiaomi AX5400 routers.

So basically I have a total of 4 WIFI networks.

I have various devices that are connected to the 2 Xiaomi routers that come from the Xiaomi router that is connected to the main router, such as Apple tv, Android boxes and more. I'm trying to access my video shares by KODI software which I think you may be familiar with, or even some other way, but I get "connection refused" error messages, and I've tried using SMB instead of DLNA or UPNP Server but nothing connected to the routers Xiaomi's doesn't work, it's like it can't find the network, even they are all connected from the same main router, I also tried With an Android box that connected directly to the main router without the split to the Xiaomi routers and I tested with KODI and DLNA server and it worked fine, it means there is some
kind of problem In connecting the split routers, do you have any idea what could be the reason? Maybe the IP address is blocked? Or other things I need to change in the main/Xiaomi router settings? Because it's really important for me to access my files that stored in my win11 PC from all the devices in the house and from all the rooms, sorry for the long dig, but I really need help.

---

Hi it is didn’t let me post the question, so i screenshot it, please help me

[image: Hi it is didn’t let me post the question, so i screenshot it, please help me]

Comment: Hi, what didn't let you post the question? You should fix that problem instead of screenshoting it.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: you should set up all but the first router as a dumb AP rather than as routers - I mean, you may have, but your "network diagram" is NOT a diagram, it's a wall of words that make little sense

Comment: So what i need to do please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Each router has NAT or Network Access Translation which limits bad guys from getting in your network when facing the internet.

The router with the computer with SMB on needs to have rules setup to allow SMB file sharing.

I am not familiar with the configuration of said routers.

From the remote PC can you even ping the computer with the SMB share?

There maybe addition firewall settings you may have to change.

Comment: From the main router i need to have rule setup to allow smb file sharing? How to do it? Can i just screenshot my main router settings and can you help me? I don't think it is related to firewall but maybe…

Comment: Because in the devices connected to the main router SMB is allowed